# Get StringArrayListExtra and instantiate it?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get an ArrayList of strings from another activity, and print out the elements like so:

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {              //this does get called
    Intent extras = this.getIntent();
    foo = extras.getStringArrayListExtra("foo");

    for (int i = 0; i < foo.size(); i++)    //error
        System.out.println(foo.get(i));
}
```

Instantiating it before getStringArrayListExtra doesn't help with the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
```

How else can I get the size of the ArrayList?

**Edit:**

This is how I pass it from one activity to another:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("foo",foo);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```

Comment: Looks like `getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("foo");` does not have any data and is `null`. Please ensure that `getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("foo");` gets the data correctly before using `foo` in for loop

Comment: share code arraylist sending ?

Comment: how do you pass your array list?

Comment: Sorry I edited it in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code snippet.  Solution is to add the typecasting to get the ArrayList from the flatten object.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("foo",foo);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);



if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {              //this does get called
Intent extras = this.getIntent();
foo = (ArrayList<? extends Object>)extras.getStringArrayListExtra("foo");

for (int i = 0; i < foo.size(); i++)    //error
    System.out.println(foo.get(i));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should get the value by using same keyword which you passed through intent .

You should get arraylist by using “foo” keyword.

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {              //this does get called
    Intent extras = this.getIntent();
    foo = extras.getStringArrayListExtra("foo");

    for (int i = 0; i < foo.size(); i++)    //error
        System.out.println(foo.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are putting the value in Intent using key **foo** , but you are getting same using **condition**. Hence it is throwing Null Pointer Exception.

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {              //this does get called
    Intent extras = this.getIntent();
    foo = extras.getStringArrayListExtra("foo");
    for (int i = 0; i < foo.size(); i++)    //condition changed to foo
        System.out.println(foo.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("foo",foo);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);



if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {              //this does get called
    Intent extras = this.getIntent();
    foo = extras.getStringArrayListExtra("foo");

    for (int i = 0; i < foo.size(); i++)    //error
        System.out.println(foo.get(i));
```

- change getStringArrayListExtara("condition") to ("foo")

Answer (score 0):

The activity puts the values for **"foo"** and not **"conditions"**.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("foo",foo);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```

To retrieve the same contents you will need to get them using same variable - **"foo"**. Additionally/optionally you can add a null check on foo arraylist and print debug line if the foo is null.

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {              //this does get called
    Intent extras = this.getIntent();
    foo = extras.getStringArrayListExtra("foo");  //get foo contents
    if(foo != null){
      for (int i = 0; i < foo.size(); i++)    
        System.out.println(foo.get(i));
    } else {
        System.out.println("foo is null"); //for debugging
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are putting "foo" as key when putting data to intent and "condition" as key while getting data from intent

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the data of ArrayList through intent on index **"foo"** and getting the value on index **"conditions"** thats why its giving **NullPointerException.**